# close a fragment when the other activity content is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 activity A and B, A uses a fragment to display the list view and B displays the content when an list item selected and the list view is closed. 
I can make the list view visible and invisible using the menu button.
When the list view is visible and when i click on the content fragment, the list view is still visible. I want to make the list invisible when I press any location in the content(Activity/fragment)

I toggle the list view visibility using the below code when I press the menu button:

```
Fragment frag = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA);
                                    frag.getView().setVisibility(8);
```

I am not sure where to use this code, when the Activity B is pressed.

Comment: Post more of your code so we can see what's going on. From your current question it is not clear if the two fragments are meant to occupy the same space or not. If they are, you should be using a `replace` fragment transaction.

Comment: If you see the developer site:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Where an Activity in tablet can have 2 fragment, selecting an item updates fragment B. In my code, there 2 separate activities in 2 separate projects. I have a menu button which can toggle the list view visibility. When the list view is visible and when I touch the activity B, I need the list view of Activity to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing what you ask. I would take a look at this: [Detecting Common Gestures.](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) Basically you can override the [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) method in an activity or view or attach. The other is too implement a Gesture Detector that tracks certain gestures, such as  pressing down, or swiping a direction.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. I gave the onTouch in the Activity A, with the case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE), but I don't see this getting called. Activity A is in a separate project than Activity B. Activity A holds a fragment which has expandable list view adaptor. Do I need to specify the on touch in the fragment/list view rather than the Activity?

Comment: It's hard without seeing your code. But the easiest way to use fragments the way you seem to want is to. Create only 1 activity then put the 2 fragments inside it. Then attach the GestureDetector to the one of the fragments.

Comment: When I touch the other fragment content, I could see the below logs 02-06 11:05:11.709: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(1969): blockWebkitDraw
02-06 11:05:11.709: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(1969): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
02-06 11:05:12.009: D/webview(1969): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
but my touch is not called.

Comment: I tried the on touch event on the body message of web view content, and it seems to work fine